# Javascript sort numbers with a variable for the field being sorted

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to sort some numbers in Javascript - this works fine, but I am trying to refactor some of the code so I am not hard coding field names.  Below is my function:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.values[0].field1 - b.values[0].field1;
});
```

The problem is that I want to also use this same functionality with `field2`

I've tried doing something like the following (simplified):

```
var sortBy = "field1";

data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.values[0].sortBy- b.values[0].sortBy;
});
```

That is looking for a literal field name of sortBy though and is not working.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `a.values[0][sortBy]`

Comment: `a.values[0][sortBy]`. Damn. You beat me to it by 13 seconds.

Comment: @Matthijs *13* seconds! ;P

Comment: @deceze: And you beat me to the close (same original question) by 19 secs. :-)

Comment: @deceze My bad! :p

Comment: @T.J.Crowder *20* seco... ah, whatever. ;)

Comment: Thanks - that original answer didn't show up in my search - appreciate the quick response(s)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> a.values[0].sortBy
> ```

```
a.values[0][sortBy]
```

Comment: @tchelidze, [why?](/review/suggested-edits/11812565)

Comment: Indeed, that suggested edit was worse than pointless. *In general*, though, code dump answers are not *useful* answers. Instead, say *what* you did, and (usually more importantly) *why*.